# Is QApplication really required for using QtSql

Tags: c++, qt, qtsql

It seems I need to instantiate a `QApplication` object and call exec on it for using `QtSql`, namely establish a database connection, execute query etc..

Am I right ? If yes why ?

Comment: What happens when you try to do that without a `QApplication`?

Comment: @user0042 The answer to that question might reflect undefined behaviour and hence not be meaningful either way.

Answer (score 2):

You might not need a `QApplication`, if you don't have a GUI, you can probably just use `QCoreApplication`.

All Qt apps must have an Application class, from the [manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#details):

> QCoreApplication contains the main event loop, where all events from
>   the operating system (e.g., timer and network events) and other
>   sources are processed and dispatched. It also handles the
>   application's initialization and finalization, as well as system-wide
>   and application-wide settings.